# Invalid character value for cast specification error occurred when mapping column of type DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 to datetime2 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, visual-studio-2017, etl

I'm creating an SSIS package to import a CSV file into a table. Currently I'm importing a flat file, creating a derived column, performing a data conversion, and then loading that to the DB.

*Package Data Flow*

[image: Package Data Flow]

The issue I'm encountering is while trying to convert a column of type `DT_DBTIMESTAMP2` to a `datetime2` its throwing the following error:

> [OLE DB Destination [78]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification.".
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification.".

the format form my data is:

```
20-NOV-18 06.09.43.928460000 PM
```

In my derived column im using the following expression which appears to be giving me the result im looking for:

```
"20" + SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,8,2) + "-" + 
    (SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "JAN" ? "01" : 
     SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "FEB" ? "02" : 
     SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "MAR" ? "03" : 
     SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "APR" ? "04" : 
     SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "MAY" ? "05" : 
     SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "JUN" ? "06" : 
     SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "JUL" ? "07" : 
     SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "AUG" ? "08" : 
     SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "SEP" ? "09" : 
     SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "OCT" ? "10" : 
     SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "NOV" ? "11" : 
     SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "DEC" ? "12" : " ") 
+ "-" + LEFT(DSTAMP,2) + " " + SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,11,2) + ":" +
SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,14,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,17,2) + "." +
SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,20,7)
```

I set up a data viewer and it appears to be giving me the desired result:

*Data Viewer Output*

[image: Data Viewer Output]

I've browsed numerous posts looking for an answer haven't found one that works for my situation. The package is making it way through to the OLE DB Destination before failing.

I've scrubbed the input file looking for anomalies and all rows are correct.

figured another set of eyes could help, any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: i didn't understood how you said that *`The issue I'm encountering is while trying to convert a String to a datetime2 its throwing the following error:`* and after that you showed that the Data Conversion output is correct which means that string are converted successfully to timestamp. Did you mapped the `DT_STR` column to the destination or the `DT_DBTIMESTAMP2` column??

Comment: The derived column is producing the desired output. I’m using the derived column to properly format the string to match what is expected by DT_DBTIMESTAMP2. Then attempting to convert the string to DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 and load it into a table. The first 3 processes complete successfully but the process fails out at the OLE DB Destination with the provided error. Hope that clears it up a bit.

Comment: Ok. Then it is better to edit the question and mention that the problem is when mapping DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 to datetime 2 column

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to (DT_DBTIMESTAMP2) inside the derived column:

```
(BT_DBTIMESTAMP2)("20" + SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,8,2) + "-" + 
(SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "JAN" ? "01" : 
 SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "FEB" ? "02" : 
 SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "MAR" ? "03" : 
 SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "APR" ? "04" : 
 SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "MAY" ? "05" : 
 SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "JUN" ? "06" : 
 SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "JUL" ? "07" : 
 SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "AUG" ? "08" : 
 SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "SEP" ? "09" : 
 SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "OCT" ? "10" : 
 SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "NOV" ? "11" : 
 SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,4,3) == "DEC" ? "12" : " ") 
 + "-" + LEFT(DSTAMP,2) + " " + SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,11,2) + ":" +
SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,14,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,17,2) + "." +
SUBSTRING(DSTAMP,20,7))
```

Comment: Tried to cast in the derived column and receive the same error.

Comment: @arrchar the question was not clear, you mentioned that the problem is when assigning string value to datetime2, now after the last edit it is more clear, i will try to figre it out